# How to setup Adobe Flash Media Server 4.5 with external Apache

Tags: apache2, video-streaming, flash-media-server

I'm trying to setup Flash Media Server with an external Apache in order to stream some vod content in a HTML5 video Player in chrome browser. 
I've followed the instructions [Adobe Help](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashmediaserver/configadmin/WSd391de4d9c7bd6093a7e2f8312a374a1bde-8000.html#WS565cbb3ff5441e2614fa39ef13121395a10-8000) but that doesn't help much. I can see FMS and FMSHttpd services running in the services list.

Normal html pages display fine, however, the video is not streaming.

1. I don't want to use the Apache that comes in the same package.
2. I'm streaming it to a html5 video element and the code goes like this in html

   `<video controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay"
       src="http://localhost/vod/sample2_1000kbps.f4v" width="480" height="352">Video Tag not supported</video>`
3. The FMS and Apache both are in a windows machine, but in different locations.
4. The video plays fine when I use the Apache of the FMS Package.

I know i might have made a mistake in several places in this complex setup, however, any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess i have figured that out. built in apache was listening to port 8134 instead of default 80. so when i put the URL as computername:8134 it all worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you are attempting to use Apache (even one you install yourself). Using another web server like IIS will not work.
2. Can you request the URL directly? http://localhost/vod/sample2_1000kbps.f4v. You will need to make sure that the manually installed Apache is configured to look at the correct location on disk, where the file is actually located.
3. That URL looks like you are trying to progressive download the file. FMS is not involved in this at all. Can you explain what you are trying to achieve in more detail.
4. If you are not using the Apache installed by FMS you should not even see FMFShhtp in the list of services.
5. Stop fmshttpd. in your manual Apache httpd.conf make sure that DocumentRoot is pointing to the correct location where the vod/sample2_1000kbps.f4v file is located. Start the manual Apache. Request the file. What is in the Apache access/error logs?

Why do you not want to use the Apache shipped with FMS?

Comment: The reason i didn't want to use built in apache was because I was not able to connect to it from any other system in the network. however, i guess i have figured that out. built in apache was listening to port 8134 instead of default 80. so when i put the URL as http://computername:8134/ it all worked fine.

Thanks for your efforts